# hive load data:how to specify file column separator and dynamic partition columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive

well I had some question on loading mysql data into hive2, and don't know how to specify the separator, I tried for serval times but got nothing.

Here below is the hive table,`id` is the partition column,

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost/> desc test;  
+-----------+------------+----------+  
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |  
+-----------+------------+----------+  
| a         | string     |          |  
| id        | int        |          |  
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

When i execute

```
load data local inpath 'file:///root/test' into table test partition (id=1);
```

it says:

```
Invalid path ''file:///root/test'': No files matching path file
```

but it do exists.

I wish to dynamic partitioned by the specified file,so i add the very column into the file like this:

```
root@<namenode|~>:#cat /root/test  
a,1  
b,2
```

but it also failed,the docs say nothing about this,i guess it doesn't support right now.
dose anyone got some idea in it? any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in the HDFS?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify column sperators it uses the command;

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Replace the ',' with your separator

Also if you want to partition a Hive table you specify the column which you want to terminate on using;

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (bar int )
PARTITIONED BY (testpartition string)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: thanks! but..donesn't 'local' means the local file system?see [LanguageManual+DML](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML).BTW,I mean how to load data in dynamic partition mode (SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict)

Comment: @cwalet Sorry my mistake, but if you are loading from a local linux path into a table with ORC compression that will not work. Not saying you are doing this just trying to rationalize my error! load data local inpath 'file:///root/test/*' into table test partition (id=1); try using this command instead of your original one and see if it works.